# Calculate progress during execution of a function in Android

Tags: android, progress-bar

I have a function:

```
 public byte[] convertFileToBytes(String path) throws IOException {

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path);
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] b = new byte[1024];

    for (int readNum; (readNum = fis.read(b)) != -1;) {
        bos.write(b, 0, readNum);
    }

    byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();

    return bytes;
}
```

which is responsible to converting a file to bytes. Given that some files are large and therefore take time to convert, how can i determine the progress during the execution of this function, i.e how can i measure progress from the first byte to the last of the file being converted in order to display this in a determinate progress bar?

Comment: You should use AsyncTask

Comment: from my understanding, will asynctask determine the progress or it will only alert me when execution is complete?

Comment: You can get the progress anytime you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use AsyncTask, the OnProgressUpdate are perfect for that

```
private class convertFileToBytes extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, byte[]> {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path);
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] b = new byte[1024];

    int byteLength = (fis.available() / b.length) + 1);
    int increment = 0;

    @Override
    protected byte[] doInBackground(String... params) {
        for (int readNum; (readNum = fis.read(b)) != -1;) {
            bos.write(b, 0, readNum);
            ++increment;                        
            publishProgress((increment/byteLength)*100);

        }
        byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();
        return bytes;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(byte[] result) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {}

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
      Log.d("progress",Integer.valueOf(progress));
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply access the progress inside the loop, for example:
`if (readNum%1000) cerr << readNum*100/totalNum << "% done\n";`

Note that you would have to find the total size of the file (`totalNum`) upfront. The `%1000` would only write every 1000 reads, not every time.
Note also that any output slows the execution down, so by informing the user about progress, it gets a bit slower.